# Folder Structure Issues In Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, directory-structure

I have a script which creates a file in a folder (the folder is named from a cell value, the file has a static name). What I'm hoping for is a script that will create a parent value (in this case a year from a cell eg. 2021) and then a sub folder under that (in this case an emplyee type which is set and NOT from a cell eg. Driver).

What I am really struggling with is getting the folder structure I want - which would ultimately look like this:

"Year" (from cell value) --> "Employee Type" (static value)--> "Employee Name" (from cell values) --> "index.html" (static value)

With the below code, I have the last two parts of the structure working but cannot get "Year" or "Employee Type" folders.

My current code is below but I cannot seem to figure out how to add the 2 folders above to this script.

```
function driverPages() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg = sh.getRange(2, 17, sh.getLastRow(), 2);
  var vs = rg.getValues().filter(r => r.every(Boolean));
  vs.forEach(r => DriveApp.getFolderById(deletedriverPages('1Xsl2r_RPgqQ1i8K3aF23hov82JmNFySu',r[0], '2020')).createFile('index.html', r[1]));
}
function deletedriverPages(parentId, name) {
  var parent = DriveApp.getFolderById(parentId);
  var id;
  var folders = parent.getFoldersByName(name);
  if (folders.hasNext()) {
    var folder = folders.next();
    id = folder.getId();
    var files = folder.getFiles();
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      var file = files.next();
      if (file.getName() == 'index.html') { file.setTrashed(true) }
    }
  }
  else {
    var folder = parent.createFolder(name);
    id = folder.getId();
  }
  return id;
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from `"Year" (from cell value) --> "Employee Type" (static value)--> "Employee Name" (from cell values) --> "index.html" (static value)`, I cannot understand your expected value in your script. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing a recursive function to traverse the folder hierarchy and create any missing folders along the way. Here is an example (not tested):

```
function driverPages() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg = sh.getRange(2, 17, sh.getLastRow(), 2);
  var vs = rg.getValues().filter(r => r.every(Boolean));
  vs.forEach(r => DriveApp.getFolderById(deletedriverPages('1Xsl2r_RPgqQ1i8K3aF23hov82JmNFySu' [r[0], 'Employee Type', '2020'])).createFile('index.html', r[1]));
}

function deletedriverPages(parent, folderNames) {
  //if parent is a string, it is assumed to be a folder ID
  if(typeof parent === "string") {
    return deletedriverPages(DriveApp.getFolderById(parent), folderNames);
  //while there are more folder names in the array, keep processing and then recursively call the function
  } else if(folderNames.length > 0) {
    let name = folderNames.pop();
    let folders = parent.getFoldersByName(name);
    //if the folder exists, get it - otherwise create it
    let folder = folders.hasNext() ?  folders.next() : parent.createFolder(name);
    return deletedriverPages(folder, folderNames);
  //when the array is empty, delete index files if they exist
  } else {
    var files = parent.getFiles();
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      var file = files.next();
      if (file.getName() === 'index.html') { file.setTrashed(true) }
    }
    return parent.getId();
  }
}
```